# How to run Android emulator in VS.NET 2015 when using Parallels on OSX?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova, parallels

I have a Cordova app.  When I select the Android emulator and try to run, I get the following errors:

```
PANIC: HOME is defined but could not find AVD_GalaxyNexus_ToolsForApacheCordova.ini file in $HOME\.android\avd
(Note: avd is searched in the order of $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME\.android\avd and $HOME\.android\avd)
```

If the above are environment variables, they do not exist.  I'm not sure where `.android\avd` is supposed to reside.

I'm in Win7.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Did you use a different user to install VS 2015?  You should find it in %HOME%\.android\avd (%HOME% on Windows == $HOME on OSX).  Regardless, you should actually be able to resolve this by creating a new AVD using the AVD Manager. You should find it in your start menu.  You can validate you are setup correctly by starting up the new virtual device you created.  Whichever AVD you have running is the one VS will deploy to.

Comment: I only have one account, which is an admin.  If I go into environment variables, there isn't anything called HOME.  I was able to create a new AVD but like the existing, it doesn't launch either.  All the AVDs are located on a network path, which might be a problem.  Is there a way to move these to C:\?  For the new AVD, I see an error in the launch about HOME could not be found.

Comment: Yeah this would not be exposed in the environment variables under system.  If you open a command prompt and type "echo %HOME%" it should tell you a location.  Home is simply the root folder where your Documents folder is located. Ex: C:\Users\myloginid

Comment: Is your home folder located on a network drive?  For example, are you running from Parallels on OSX or a VM that is sharing your home folder from another operating system?  What does the ADT_HOME say in Tools > Options > Tools for Apache Cordova > Environment Variable Overrides?

Comment: I'm on Parallels on OSX.  I believe the home folder is on my C: drive. None of those variables are checked.  The first one is "C:\Users\machinename\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk"

Comment: Is the "Shared Profile" option checked in your VM?  That can cause issues since it puts things like your documents folder on a network share under the hood.(Options>Sharing>Shared Profile:)  You may also find this article of interest that describes how to run the Android emulator on your OSX side and connect to it from Windows for improved performance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn913137.aspx

Comment: Awesome!  That fixed it.  The emulator now runs.  But do you have any idea why it takes so incredibly long for the emulator to start?  It's a while before I reach the unlock screen.

Comment: You're running an already slow emulator inside a VM - So it will be very slow.  You should check "Options > Enable nested virtualization" which should help, but the link I included tells you how to actually start up the Android emulator on the OSX side of your machine and connect to it from Windows. You then get hardware acceleration, GPU support, etc. I'll post this as an answer for everyone to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Parallels on OSX, there are a few things you need to do.  First, two important settings for your VM:

1. Uncheck the "Shared Profile" option: Options > Sharing > Shared Profile
2. Enable nested virtualization: Options > Enable nested virtualization

By default, Parallels puts your documents folder among other things on a network share which does not work very well. Turning off Shared Profile fixes that problem. Enabling nested virtualization should improve performance.

You can also setup the Android emulator to run on the OSX side for maximum performance pretty easily.  Here's instructions for that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn913137.aspx

Finally, here's some additional general guidance on using Parallels: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn878133.aspx