# Cordova not Building Parallels osx/win10

Tags: android, macos, cordova, parallels, cordova-win10

I would like some help on this. Tried searching everywhere and trying everything but with no luck. here is the result if I run the build.bat[image: Command Prompt Window]

I am using Windows 10 with VS Community 2015 running from a Mac via Parallels
Should you require more detail please let me know.
I am quite new to Mac :-)

Answer (score 0):

After searching everywhere i noticed it was cause it was trying to launch the grade on the mac. after seeing this post i managed to fix it by unpicking "Share Mac user folders with Windows" Hope it can help someone having the same issue [How to run Android emulator in VS.NET 2015 when using Parallels on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217889/how-to-run-android-emulator-in-vs-net-2015-when-using-parallels-on-osx/30245953#30245953)[image]