# What TCP/UDP ports does Xamarin for VS use?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, parallels

I use Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin VS in Parallels on Mac but Android emulators work fine only in Mac OS so I had to create a ssh tunnel and redirected some ports from Windows to Mac to Android emulators worked. I did it experimental I didn't know what ports I had to redirect exactly that all Xamarin services worked.

What ports should I redirect that all Xamarin services (Inspector, Profiler and etc) work exactly?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/13862/ports-required-for-installation-behind-firewall

Comment: [This is about `parallels on osx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217889/how-to-run-android-emulator-in-vs-net-2015-when-using-parallels-on-osx), it will help you.