# Android Emulator not working in Parallels 15

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2019, parallels

My job gave me a new MacBook Pro with Parallels 15 installed. I installed Visual Studio 2019 and turned on Hyper-V.

When I debug a Xamarin project, my Android emulator take a long time to come up but never fully loads. It also eats up CPU time as well.

I am wondering if anyone else has this issue or had this issue and now have it working correctly. Any help would be appreciated as its my first week on the job. :-o

Comment: Anyone have android emulator working with VS2019 and Parallels?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30245953/1566099